# double data type return error 'Decimal overflow' in prestoSQL

Tags: error-handling, double, decimal, presto, sqldatatypes

I tried to debug my query in prestoSQL.

I got an error with **"Decimal Overflow"** whereas my datatype is already double. It's a big table with more than 300 columns and there are about 250's calculation with cast as double separated in many CTE's.

Is there any suggestion to prevent this to happen again ? Or which datatype is more robust ? double or DECIMAL(38,38) ? Or even they are same

Any suggestion ?
This is the only information I got :(
[image: this is the only information shared with me lol.]
PS : I can not really share the code since it's very big query and confidential